# Matrix Synapse setup | Postgresql username and password issue

Tags: postgresql, matrix-synapse

I am trying to run Matrix Synapse along with the Postgresql using docker-compose per configuration in the official tutorial https://youtu.be/JCsw1bbBjAM.

However it only works with the username and password declared as it is in the tutorial. Whenever I use other credentials in my configs I am able to authenticate directly in Postgres container using PSQL with the declared credentials from docker-compose.yaml, but Synapse throws **passwrod authentication failed** error message

I tried with the exact same credentials as shown in the tutorial and it worked.

I expect to be able to set my own creds in configurations.

Maatrix Synapse image version is **v1.81.0**, Posdtgresql uses **postgresql:15-alpine** image